# Run MSBuildTask from visual studio add-in

Tags: visual-studio-addins

I have a custom Visual Studio add-in that runs an IDL compiler and add the generated C# source files to the project.

My add-in runs the IDL compiler when IDL definitions are saved and also on before build event.

I want to move the execution of IDL compiler to MSBuildTask, to allow the work to be done out of the main thread, but need a way to execute my custom task from the add-in when an IDL file is saved.

The maim reason i want to run the compiler in a MSBuildTask is that this avoid the use of the main thread, and keeps Visual Studio interface responsiveness.